# 6 DoF rigid body equations and tensor of inertia

Tags: reference-frames, rigid-body-dynamics, moment-of-inertia

I am writing here as I have a doubt on the tensor of inertia found in the Euler's equations.

As far as I have understood, people usually solve the Euler's equations in "body coordinates" as:

$m \dot{v}_g + \omega \times(mv_g) = F$

$I\dot{\omega}+\omega\times  I \omega = M$

Mass is constant and does not change with time.

I have a (silly) question on the second equation in particular:

- Is the tensor of inertia a constant matrix, while the body is translating and rotating? Should I compute it with respect to the center of gravity of the body and forget about it?

Comment: Can you please define $v_g$ and $\omega$ exactly (basis vectors, what is measured).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Translation**

\begin{align*}
 &\mathbf{v}_I=\mathbf{S}\,\mathbf{v}_B\quad\Rightarrow\,
 \mathbf{\dot{v}}_I=\mathbf{\dot S}\,\mathbf{v}_B+\mathbf{S}\,\mathbf{\dot{v}}_B\\
 &\text{with}\quad \mathbf{\dot S}=\mathbf{S}\,\mathbf{\omega}_B^\times\\
 &\Rightarrow
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
  &\mathbf{\dot{v}}_I=\mathbf{S}\,\left(\mathbf{\omega}_B\times \,\mathbf{v}_B\right)+\mathbf{S}\,\mathbf{\dot{v}}_B\\
\end{align*}
Newton equation
\begin{align*}
 &m\,\mathbf{\dot{v}}_I=\mathbf{F}_I\quad \text{or}\quad, 
 m\,\underbrace{\mathbf{S}^T\,\mathbf{\dot{v}}_I}_{(\mathbf{\dot{v}}_I)_B}=\mathbf{S}^T\,\mathbf{F}_I=\mathbf{F}_B
\end{align*}
you obtain
\begin{align*}
 &\mathbf{S}^T\,\mathbf{\dot{v}}_I=\left(\mathbf{\omega}_B\times \,\mathbf{v}_B\right)+\mathbf{\dot{v}}_B=\frac{\mathbf{F}_B}{m}\\
 &\boxed{\,\mathbf{\dot{v}}_B=\frac{\mathbf{F}_B}{m}-\left(\mathbf{\omega}_B\times \,\mathbf{v}_B\right)\,}
\end{align*}

**Rotation**

Euler equation in B_system

\begin{align*}
 &\boxed{\,I_B\,\mathbf{\dot{\omega}}_B+\mathbf{\omega}_B\,\times \left(I_B\,\mathbf{\omega}_B\right)=\mathbf\tau_B\,}
\end{align*}

- $\mathbf S~$ transformation matrix between Body and Inertial system
- Subscript $~B~$ Body system
- Subscript $~I~$ Inertial system

**Notice** that with those two equations of motion, you don't get the position  and the orientation (angles) of the rigid body , you need additional equations

---

**Edit**

**Rotation Matrix $~\mathbf{S}~$**

\begin{align*}
 &\mathbf{S}=\mathbf{S}_z(\psi)\,\mathbf{S}_x(\varphi)\,\mathbf{S}_y(\vartheta)\\
 &\mathbf{S}=
 \left[ \begin {array}{ccc} \cos \left( \psi \right) &-\sin \left(
\psi \right) &0\\  \sin \left( \psi \right) &\cos
 \left( \psi \right) &0\\  0&0&1\end {array} \right]
\,
 \left[ \begin {array}{ccc} 1&0&0\\  0&\cos \left(
\varphi  \right) &-\sin \left( \varphi  \right) \\  0
&\sin \left( \varphi  \right) &\cos \left( \varphi  \right)
\end {array} \right]
\,
 \left[ \begin {array}{ccc} \cos \left( \vartheta  \right) &0&\sin
 \left( \vartheta  \right) \\  0&1&0
\\  -\sin \left( \vartheta  \right) &0&\cos \left(
\vartheta  \right) \end {array} \right]
\\
&\text{with}\quad \mathbf{\dot S}=\mathbf{S}\,\mathbf{\omega}^\times\\
 &\Rightarrow\\
 &\begin{bmatrix}
                  \omega_x \\
                  \omega_y \\
                  \omega_z \\
                \end{bmatrix}
 =\underbrace{ \left[ \begin {array}{ccc} \cos \left( \vartheta  \right) &0&-\cos
 \left( \varphi  \right) \sin \left( \vartheta  \right)
\\  0&1&\sin \left( \varphi  \right)
\\  \sin \left( \vartheta  \right) &0&\cos \left(
\varphi  \right) \cos \left( \vartheta  \right) \end {array} \right]
}_{\mathbf{J}_R}
\,\begin{bmatrix}
    \dot{\varphi} \\
    \dot{\vartheta} \\
    \dot{\psi} \\
  \end{bmatrix}\\
  &\Rightarrow
 \end{align*}
\begin{align*}
 & \boxed{\,\begin{bmatrix}
    \dot{\varphi} \\
    \dot{\vartheta} \\
    \dot{\psi} \\
  \end{bmatrix}=\left[ \begin {array}{ccc} \cos \left( \vartheta  \right) &0&\sin
 \left( \vartheta  \right) \\  {\frac {\sin \left(
\varphi  \right) \sin \left( \vartheta  \right) }{\cos \left( \varphi
 \right) }}&1&-{\frac {\sin \left( \varphi  \right) \cos \left(
\vartheta  \right) }{\cos \left( \varphi  \right) }}
\\  -{\frac {\sin \left( \vartheta  \right) }{\cos
 \left( \varphi  \right) }}&0&{\frac {\cos \left( \vartheta  \right) }
{\cos \left( \varphi  \right) }}\end {array} \right]
  \,
 \begin{bmatrix}
                  \omega_x \\
                  \omega_y \\
                  \omega_z \\
                \end{bmatrix}\,}\tag 3
\end{align*}

Singularity at $~\varphi=\pi/2~$

**Inertial Position vector $~\mathbf R_I~$**

\begin{align*}
&\mathbf{v}_I=\mathbf{S}\,\mathbf{v}_B\\&\Rightarrow
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
 & \boxed{\,\mathbf{\dot{R}}_I=\mathbf{v}_I\,}\tag 4
\end{align*}

all together you obtained 12 first order differential equations for a rigid body solution

Comment: Hello Eli, thanks for this. I am going to solve this numerically so those two equations  should be enough for me. What about $I_B$? Is it a constatare whipe the body is moving?

Comment: The Inertia tensor is constant in body system

Comment: I was suspecting it. Should I compute it once with respect to the center of gravity?

Comment: Yes you can , because it is constant

Comment: Hi Eli, reading again your answer, I have had another doubt.  The euler equation in B sistem will give me some $\omega_B$. I have seen that I can link it to  the rate of variation of Euler's angles using a matrix transformation which might end up to be singular or $\theta=90$. Any suggestion to get rid of this? Also, waht do you mean with your statment in the "notice"? That those equations gives you back the omega and v and not x and angles? Thanks

Comment: I think I got the point... After Euler equation I need to add another set of kinematic relations (1st order ode) to link the rotation rate to the orientation. To avoid the issue with $\theta=90$, I'll likely need to use quaternions! That will be good fun.

Comment: @alie89 on which axis is the $~\theta~$ rotation ?
you can avoid the singularly by choosing the Euler angles, you don't need quaternions. which physical problem you want to solve ?

Comment: @alie89 see additional  equations

Comment: I need to code a 6 dof solver to be interfaced with my CFD code.  In pills, I 'll get forces and moments from CFD on an STL like geometry, and, given the forces, I'll need to update the body position, orientation and velocity solving the equations we are talking about.  The fear about the Euler's angle is the "Gimbal lock", as I'll have to revert back from body coodinates to fixed earth ones.

Comment: Do you know how to deal with it? I cannot ensure that $\phi$ will be different from $\pi/2$ or close to it.

Comment: perhaps this can help you ?
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/578682/using-higher-order-derivatives-of-quaternions-in-equations-of-motion

Comment: Hello @Eli, thanks for the support, I managed to write down a fortran code for the 6dof rigid body dynamics with quaternion formulation using adams-bashforth 4th order! It was quite fun and instructive :)

Comment: What is $v_B$ since on the body frame the center of mass is fixed and therefore $v_B=0$, or is it the inertial frame velocity on the body basis-vectors?

Comment: @alie89 - ditto. My [Fortran 3D MBD with quaternions repo](https://github.com/ja72/FortranMbdVector). Specifically I wanted to use a tracking point _not at the center of mass_ and thus I ended up with [this function](https://github.com/ja72/FortranMbdVector/blob/e5784a6830e74e134552f7f05c75bc6983882a93/Fortran/Source/mod_vectors_dynamics.f90#L214).

Comment: @alie89 - I also found the minimum time step for accurate results with RK4 is such that the fastest rotating body does not undergo more than 0.5° of rotation for each time step.

Comment: Hello John, ah that's cool, I googled a bit to find an already existing code but did not find yours, I'll have a look! Does it use quaternions to avoid gimbal lock? Also I know RK might be better, but I do not want to re-evaluate the forces in the rk steps as they come from the flow solver and they are expensive to compute. That's way I am going with a multistep here.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou $~v_B~$ is inertial velocity given in B coordinate system

Comment: @alie89 - yes I am using quaternions instead of Euler angles to prevent gimbal lock. But I am using the inertial reference frame for my calculations, so MMOI needs to be re-evaluated at each time step. That is not a bottleneck tough. Also I investigate the requirement for renormalization of the quaternions and concluded the extra computation is worth the bump in accuracy.

Comment: Cool, using inertial fram would be nice for me as well to be honest. However since I do not know the shape of the bodies, I am not sure it will be easy to compute MMOI every time step. I was planning to get it from CAD once and forget about it using body coordinates!

Comment: @alie89 - I do not re-calculate the MMOI at each step. I start with the MMOI in body coordinates and bring it to the inertial basis-vectors with $${\bf I}_{C}={\rm R}{\bf I}_{{\rm body}}{\rm R}^{\intercal}$$

Comment: Yes that's a good way indeed. I'll have definitevly a look at your code then!

Comment: Guys, I am looking for some test cases... I have already done the projectile, but I would like to do something more challenging, do you have any idea?